# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 46 byte allocation with 0 free bytes and -6MB until OOM

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I have a simple thread that every minute runs a very simple query on sqlite and fetches only one row from database. this sql query is really slight and tiny. But I  sometimes receive a crash report from some customer's devices:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 46 byte allocation with 0 free bytes and -6MB until OOM
```

Unfortunately I do not have more data about the issue. How can I figure it out? 46 byte is not a wealth of memory to throw an OutOfMemoryError!

This is my thread:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (locationThread == null) {
        locationThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                locationmanager.LocationManager locationManager = new LocationManager(VasActivity.this);
                while (!VasActivity.this.isFinishing()) {
                    try {
                        lastLocation = locationManager.getLastLocation(LocationManager.Accuracy.TrackingAccuracy, 120);
                        Thread.sleep(60000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {

                    }
                }
            }
        });
        locationThread.start();
    }
}
```

Here is the getLatLocation() method:

```
@Nullable
public LocationModel getLastLocation(float accuracy, int timeSpan) {
    LocationModel locationModel = getItem(new Query().from(Location.LocationTbl)
            .whereAnd(Criteria.lesserThan(Location.Accuracy, accuracy)
                    .and(Criteria.isNull(Location.EventType))).orderByDescending(Location.Date));

    if (locationModel == null)
        return null;
    long currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    long pointTime = locationModel.Date.getTime();
    long t = (currentTime - pointTime) / 1000;
    if (t < timeSpan)
        return locationModel;
    else
        return null;
}
```

and new query() returns the following raw query:

```
SELECT * FROM "Location" where Accuracy < accuracy ORDER BY Date LIMIT 1;
```

*I do not stop the thread when the user closes the activity. Is it the cause of the problem? I have a loop that each iteration waits for a minute and does something. I break the loop if user dismisses the activit*y

Comment: Why haven't you posted your query ?

Comment: minus 6MB until OOM! The device seems to be confused.

Comment: probably there is a problem with your code (memory leak), or problably a problem with user device.

Comment: You don't have data, but you have code, right? Please post your code as well.

Comment: Without the code it is almost impossible to see what you are doing wrong, I can only guess that your database actions contain memory leeks, but with the code I hope I could help a bit more

Comment: @MarkGilchrist I just added the code. I hope it might help to figure out the problem.

Comment: if your goal is to get the position at a fixed time (i.e. every 6000ms) I suggest you to use a broadcast receiver and a alarm manager

Comment: @Saret I have already used a broadcast receiver somewhere else to record the position in the table Location in database. I read from that table every minute to find the last position that i have.

Comment: @a.toraby yes but I suggest you to do the same think not only to store the position but also to read the position. However the problem is weird, seem that getting location under a thread can lead to memory leak, maybe the LocationManager class is a singleton and has a bug inside?

Comment: where are you freeing the cursor? how many data points do you have?

Comment: @MarkGilchrist Inside the getItem() method I close it. I have less than 1000 rows

Comment: Are you sure you are not creating new threads everytime? Put a debugger on your code and try to make sure.

Comment: @WesleyDeKeirsmaeker I put a condition `if (locationThread == null)` to create a new one